# Sending UTM parameters with analytics.js

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

On our website we are transitioning from the old ga.js over to analytics.js.

I've been able to successfully transition most of the code over to the new trackers and send page views, transactions, and events. However, when my marketing team is creating links for their campaigns that include UTM params and those params don't appear to be translating into our analytics dashboard. The source and medium don't seem to be correctly translating even though the UTM variables are in the URLs.

I feel like I've searched everything out and can't seem to find what I need. How do I process UTM params with analytics.js?

Comment: This works exactly as it did with ga.js. I'd wager that some configuration issue strips them out before they are sent (redirects that strip parameters, or rewriting the "location" field or something like that).  Did you have a look with the Google Analytics Debugger (or simply in the network panel) to see if the parameters are indeed being sent ?

Comment: @EikePierstorff I'll have a closer look. I've been using Google Tag Assistant to inspect the codes. Perhaps I'm using the wrong tool. I am also using the linker and doing some cross domain tracking, could that be a culprit?